# Need To Fail A Match If It Is Successful

Tags: c#, regex

I have this pattern in C#:

```
 string WWPNMatchString = @"port-wwn\s+\(vendor\)\s+:(?<wwpn>..:..:..:..:..:..:..:..)";
```

I have file with these two lines that occur in pairs several times in the file:

port-wwn (vendor)           :50:01:73:80:12:60:01:41
permanent-port-wwn (vendor) :50:01:73:80:12:60:01:41

I only want to match the first line.  There are other lines that screw up the data I am parsing where the second line looks like this:
permanent-port-wwn (vendor) :00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00

So, I don't want to match the line that includes permanent.  I could do a separate if to check the incoming string but that is messy.  the online site I use to check my regular expressions fails the second line, but C# doesn't after the code is compiled.

Comment: It sounds like you want a negative look-ahead assertion.

Comment: To test your regex string quickly try this http://regexhero.net/tester/

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me that the pattern that I don't want always starts with 00:

so I changed the regex to:

```
string WWPNMatchString = @"port-wwn\s+\(vendor\)\s+:(?<wwpn>[1-9].:..:..:..:..:..:..:..)";
```

this will exclude anything where the wwpn group starts with 0 - the value I am after, valid values never start with 0.

Answer (score 0):

A regex

```
string WWPNMatchString = @"^port-wwn\s+\(vendor\)\s+:(?<wwpn>..:..:..:..:..:..:..:..)";
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're reading the file line by line, and each line is processed as a separate string?

You can force the match to begin at the start of the string by using `^`, like this:

```
@"^port-wwn\s+\(ven...
```

This will exclude the lines starting with "permanent-".

Comment: thanks.  I spent some time searching but couldn't figure out a way to ask Google what I wanted. :)  I am searching the file, well parts of it anyway, line by line.